# Zoom in on a photo in canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, zooming

I was searching for a couple of days how to solve this problem and I decided to ask here for the help.
The thing is, I made a canvas that is 640x480px and preloaded it with an image.
After I used the mouse to select the area that is going to be zoomed in (I used a draggable square, same type like if you would press mouse on windows desktop and select multiple icons) I changed the canvas to be 480x480px (since the zoom in part of the photo is a square), and within that new canvas I have displayed a new zoomed in part of that photo.

My question is: since I am doing all of this so I can zoom in on someones face so I can get a user to more precisely place dots on eyes and mouth (face recognition software like thing) how can I get real coordinates of these dots? In respect to an original image and original canvas that was 640x480px.

Everything is in pure javascript no jQuery, and without any js libraries

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The same way you'd convert between Fahrenheit and Celsius: decide on a reference point and adjust your scale. The reference point is easy: (0, 0) in the zoomed context is the upper left corner of the selected area in the original context. For the scale, convert the zoomed click point from pixels to percentages. A click at (120, 240) is a click at (25%, 50%). Then multiply that percentage by the size of the selected area and add the reference point offset.

```
// Assume the user selected in the 640x480 canvas a 223x223
// square whose upper left corner is (174, 36),
let zoomArea = {x: 174, y: 36, size: 223};

// and then clicked (120, 260) in the new 480x480 canvas.
let pointClicked = {x: 120, y: 260};

function getOriginalCoords(area, clicked) {
  const ZOOMED_SIZE = 480;

  // Get the coordinates of the clicked point in the zoomed
  // area, on a scale of 0 to 1.
  let clickedPercent = {
    x: clicked.x / ZOOMED_SIZE,
    y: clicked.y / ZOOMED_SIZE
  };

  return {
    x: clickedPercent.x * area.size + area.x,
    y: clickedPercent.y * area.size + area.y
  };
}

console.log(getOriginalCoords(zoomArea, pointClicked));
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it today

Answer (score 0):

At the end I did it this way

```
// get bounding rect of canvas
var rectangle = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

// position of the point in respect to new 480x480 canvas
var xPositionZoom = e.clientX - crosshairOffSet - rectangle.left;
var yPositionZoom = e.clientY - crosshairOffSet - rectangle.top;

// position of the point in respect to original 640x480 canvas
var xPosition = rect.startX + (rect.w * (xPositionZoom / canvas.width));
var yPosition = rect.startY + (rect.h * (yPositionZoom / canvas.height));
```